# Quadratic bound on $\sin^2(\theta)$

Tags: inequality, trigonometry, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the the function
$$
   A \sin^2(\theta)
$$
where $ A \in \mathbb{R}, ~ A > 0$ and $\theta$ is some angle.

I am working on a suboptimal control problem in which I am interested in controlling $\theta$. The particular method I am hoping to apply is valid if I can place bound on the nonlinearity that is quadratic in $\theta$. That is, I would need to show
$$
   A \sin^2(\theta) \leq B \theta^2 ~~ \forall ~ \theta
$$
for some $B \in \mathbb{R}$.

My first thought is to let $A=B$ which leads to
$$
    \sin^2(\theta) \leq \theta^2
$$
I am not sure how to verify that this is true. Visually, if we plot both sides of the inequality on the same plot, it looks like the inequality is valid. However, looks like and proven to be are two very different things. We can take the square root of both sides and say that
$$
  | \sin(\theta) | \leq | \theta |
$$
But I don't know how to take this any further and it is not clear to me how to show that the inequality holds, or not, for all $\theta$. Any nudges in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The stated inequality is true for all real $\theta$; there are multiple proofs, depending on 1. your definition of $\sin\theta$ (e.g., triangle ratios, solution of an ODE, power series) and 2. what properties of sine are "known." It might help to edit the question to add these details.

Comment: Note: The derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$, which is absolutely bounded by $1$. From this you can deduce that $\lvert\sin(x)\rvert\le\lvert x\rvert$ for all real $x$.

Comment: Thank you. Very simple as I suspected it would be.

Answer (score 0):

Red: $y=|\sin x|$

Blue: $y=|x|$

[image: Graphs]

Comment: Hi Lanier. Thanks for the reply. I did this also (also using Desmos). We can see that the inequality is true for large $x$ say $|x|>1$. And we can say it looks true for small $x$ also. What we can't say from just the plot is that it is absolutely true for all $x$. For example, continually zoom in near the origin. The lines appear to overlap but do they actually? Zoom in more and the plots still appear to overlap. We could zoom in forever and not see conclusively that the inequality holds. The plot tells me that the inequality is likely true, now I need the math to actually prove it.

Comment: They only intersect for $x=0$. Do you know the Taylor series for sine?

Answer (score 0):

$2\sin^2x=1-\cos(2x)$. The cosine series is alternating (for real $x$). And for all $|x|<1$ its terms are falling. Thus the expression is alternatingly bounded above and below by the partial sums of the series. In consequence
$$
2x^2-\frac43 x^4\le 1-\cos(2x)=2\sin ^2x\le 2x^2.
$$
Obviously, for $|x|>1$ the inequality for the upper bound is trivial.